Why doesn't charge flow from a charged capacitor to an uncharged one when the circuit is open?
Consider the following setup:

Let $AB$ and $CD$ be identical capacitors with capacitance $C'$. Before switch S is closed, the energy of the system is $E = \frac{Q^2}{2C'}$.
Now, when switch $S$ is closed, if $Q/2$ charge migrates to plate $C$, charge $-Q/2$ is induced on the inner side of plate $D$ and $+Q/2$ on the outer side of plate $D$. This effectively charges both capacitors to $Q/2$ and we can see that the system's total energy is now $E = \frac{Q^2}{4C'}$ which is lower than the initial. But I've been told that charge doesn't flow from $B$ to $C$ when the circuit is open. Why is my line of reasoning wrong?
If the charge on $B$ is held by $A$, why doesn't $A$ polarise allowing the charge from $B$ to flow from $B$ to $C$? Is the situation an unstable equilibrium?

How is charge migrating to C with the switch open?

@BobD I forgot to mention that the switch is closed after the energy calculation. Edited for clarity

Then what did you mean by "but I've been told that charge doesn't flow from B to C when the circuit is open"?

I meant that charge wont flow unless A and D are joined or an external potential difference is applied.

$\dots$if Q/2 charge migrates to plate C $\dots$ - It does not as the $+Q$ charge on plate $B$ is held in position by the attraction of $-Q$ charge on plate $A$.

Does this answer your question? When I connect in series two floating capacitors, one charged and the other not charged, does current flow?

@JohnRennie I checked that thread out before posting here, that talks more about charges rearranging via a path, my question is more about what stops the plates from polarizing and enabling that path.

The answer does appear counterintuitive at first glance - it's often designed that way to test understanding.
If B was by itself, its charge would flow to C when the switch is closed. But with the presence of A, as soon as a positive charge leaves B, the A/B setup is unbalanced and net negative, attracting that same positive charge back. Thus, no charge will ultimately move to C.
You can also think of it this way: imagine you start the problem with A by itself, and then the B/C/D system is brought to within inductive range of A (switch closed, net positive charge +Q). This will induce the positive charges to B.

Why wouldn't the charge on plate A also polarise to reduce the energy of the system?

@failedCaptcha that would increase the energy of A more than it would decrease the energy of B/C/D

That makes sense, but would it be possible to have some mathematical evidence of this fact?

@failedCaptcha sure, it's too cumbersome to do it in a comment but you can calculate the total energy of any charge setup using Energy = $\int |\vec{E}|^2 dV$. Then approximate this charge configuration as a series of dipoles. As shown above the dipole is charge Q with distance d between the plates. The second setup would be two dipoles of Q/2: one between A/B and the other between A/C. Remember D has to stay neutral.

When the switch is closed charge does not "migrate" from B to C. The charge on B is held there by the attraction of the charge on A.
What does happen is the existing charge on C is redistributed so that electrons on C move to the side of C facing B leaving the opposite side of C facing D positively charged.
Hope this helps.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but is this similar to an unstable equilibrium in mechanics?

@failedCaptcha What type of "unstable equilibrium" did you have in mind?

You describe how both the plates C and D would become polarized. You then claim that this does not result in an electric field between C and D, but that is only true if the capacitor plates are infinitely large no? If you have 2 finite sized polarized objects arranged as you described I would expect a field between them.

@Zaph what do you mean by infinitely large?

@Zaph actually only C gets polarized. I corrected my answer.  Thanks

I meant a capacitor consisting of 2 parallel plates extending infinitely in both of their spacial directions. In that case any kind of polarization of the plates will not influence the fields outside of them because the field generated by the positive and negative charges will be independent of the distance too the plates. But generally that would not be the case.

The Gauss law argument in your correction again only holds for plate capacitor that is extending infinitely in both directions, otherwise you have no reason to assume the field to be equal on your chosen closed surface around your polarized capacitor plate. Unless I misinterpreted how you intended to use Gauss law that is.

Thinking about it I come to believe that both C and D would become polarized as described in your original answer and that would result in a weak field inside the right capacitor. The effect should be weaker the higher the extension of the plates is compared to their thickness.

@Zaph my problem with that is the redistribution of charge on C does not result in a net charge on C  and therefore by Gauss no field produced by C between C and D

@BobD Something like a person holding the pendulum bob off the mean position, ideally the pendulum 'wants' to swing down to a lower energy state but the person holding it doesn't allow it to do so.

@failedCaptcha That kind of describes why no charge migrates from B to C. Instead of a person holding the charge on B, the charge on A does the "holding"

@BobD Imagine 2 dipoles next to each other each of them is charge neutral (monopol moment is $0$), yet you would have a field between them. Gauss law does not contradict this as the contribution of the field on one side of a dipole threw a closed area around one dipole will be canceled by the field going threw the closed area on the other side of that dipole.

@Zaph Having trouble visualizing your Gaussian surfaces

@BobD I am having trouble visualizing yours :D. But I am pretty sure you don‘t want to claim that a dipole does not produce a field, just because it has no net charge, so why would you claim that about the a polarized capacitor plate?

@Zaph You're right there would be a field produced by plate C viewing it as an infinite line of dipoles. But I believe the effect of that field on the charge on plate D would be much less compared to the effect of an infinite line of charge of plate C on plate D

@BobD Funnily enough if the plate C actually was infinitly extended in both directions polarizing it would really induce no field at D. But for a finite plate geometry I agree with what you said.
